# How to use ACF fields in popup

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This function shows my popup.

```
 $('.call-hunt-btn').on('click', callHunt);

 function callHunt(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.arcticmodal({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'wp-content/themes/beton/modals/modal-feedback.php',
        overlay: {
            css: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: .75
            }
        },
        afterOpen: function(){
            setMaskPhone();
            setDataSBJS('.arcticmodal-container');
        }
    });
}
```

It uses a php template. I want to use ACF fields in this template. 
If I just write: `<?php the_field('class'); ?>`, but nothing happens.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Where are you writing that JS code?

Comment: In a separate file.And include this file in bottom of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding your javascript via wp_enqueue_script() function, you could expose the ACF values via the wp_localize_script() function (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

The wp_localize_script() function creates a Javascript object based on the values set in the PHP array supplied to the wp_localize_script(). The ACF values can then be access from the Javascript object using dot notation.